# Async select of Stream vectors in Rust

Tags: asynchronous, rust

I'm writing an async function to receive messages from a data bus, and also receive an internal stop message from a channel to stop the receiver. I have a vector of messages to receive: Vec<(SomeType, SomeOtherType), where SomeType is meant to be data samples , and SomeOtherType is meant to be events about the data samples.

To asynchronously receive all SomeType and SomeOtherType, I need to do a for loop as seen below in the minimal reproducible example:

The complete code is available in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=07798d196880ea1c9cd15129a695a39c).

```rust
async fn async_infinite_loop(
    dr_streams: Vec<(Receiver<SomeType>, Receiver<SomeOtherType>)>,
    stop_message: Receiver<bool>,
) {
    // For each reader_data:
    // 2. Select!{} on the streams, and call the handler with the corresponding subscribers list.
    // 3. Don't stop until running = false
    let mut running = true;

    println!("Start async infinite loop");

    while running {
        // Asynchronously select each data reader stream and event stream.
        // The for loop runs all select! call simultaneously.
        for (some_type_receiver, some_other_type_receiver) in &dr_streams {
            select! {
                recv(some_type_receiver) -> sample => {
                    println!("Received sample: {sample:?}")
                }

                recv(some_other_type_receiver) -> event => {
                    println!("Received sample: {event:?}")
                }

                // Wait for the shutdown message to be received.
                // This recv on stop_message is done in all iterations of the
                // for loop.
                recv(stop_message) -> _ => {
                    println!("Received stop event");
                    running = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem: The `for` loop does not listen asynchronously to each branch of the loop at the same time, but waits for the `select!` of the first iteration to end (i.e. receive a message destined to Stream0 or OtherStream0), then to second one, etc...

As seen in the playground example, when I send messages in the good order, they are all received, but when I send messages in a random order, only messages that follow the for loop listening order are received.

How to listen to all the streams in `Vec<(SomeStream, SomeOtherStream)>` and to a stop message, all at the same time ?

Note: this question is a repost from [code-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/287540/validating-select-behavior-in-for-loop-in-rust?noredirect=1#comment572699_287540) stack exchange where I posted before finding this problem. I asked to close the question there to post it in SO since it is more appropriate for debug help.

---

Some context about other things that I tried:

I also tried to use the `select_all` function as below, but I can't manage to do it because of following error.

```rust
async fn async_infinite_loop(
    &self,
    data_readers: Vec<DataReader<T>>,
    handler: ReceiveHandler<T>,
    mut message_rx: Receiver<InternalEventMessage>,
)
{
    let mut running = true;

    // For each data_reader:
    // 1. Get the async sample stream & dr_stream of the data_reader
    // 2. Select!{} on the streams, and call the handler with the corresponding subscribers list.
    // 3. Don't stop until running = false

    // Create vectors to store all the streams
    let mut dr_streams: Vec<(DataReaderStream<T>, DataReaderEventStream<T>)> = vec![];

    // Initialize the streams
    for data_reader in data_readers {
        let dr_stream = data_reader.async_sample_stream();
        let dr_event_stream = dr_stream.async_event_stream();
        dr_streams.push((dr_stream, dr_event_stream));
    }

    while running {

        let mut next_some_dr_stream = vec![];
        let mut next_some_dr_stream_event = vec![];
        
        // Create the vector of futures to select
        for (dr_stream, dr_stream_event) in &mut dr_streams {
            next_some_dr_stream.push(dr_stream.select_next_some());
            next_some_dr_stream_event.push(dr_stream_event.select_next_some());
        }

        let dr_stream_futures = select_all(next_some_dr_stream);
        let dr_stream_event_futures = select_all(next_some_dr_stream_event);

        select! {
            (result, index, other_futures) = dr_stream_futures.await => {
                match result {
                    Ok(sample) => (handler)(&self.sender, sample),
                    Err(error) => error!("Error while reading sample: {}", error)
                }
            },
            (result, index, other_futures) = dr_stream_event_futures.await => {
                match result {
                    Ok(event) => debug!("DataReader event: {event:?}"),
                    Err(error) => error!("Error while on reader event: {}", error)
                }
            }

            _opt_msg = message_rx.next().fuse() => {
                debug!("Internal message received");
                running = false;
            }
        };
    }

    info!("InnerDdsReceiver stops async infinite loop");
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `(Result<Sample<T, <T as Keyed>::K>, rustdds::dds::Error>, usize, Vec<SelectNextSome<'_, rustdds::with_key::DataReaderStream<T>>>): FusedFuture` is not satisfied
   --> src/dds_receiver.rs:166:13
    |
166 | /             select! {
167 | |                 (result, index, other_futures) = dr_stream_futures.await => {
168 | |                     match result {
169 | |                         Ok(sample) => (handler)(&self.sender, sample),
...   |
183 | |                 }
184 | |             };
    | |_____________^ the trait `FusedFuture` is not implemented for `(Result<Sample<T, <T as Keyed>::K>, rustdds::dds::Error>, usize, Vec<SelectNextSome<'_, rustdds::with_key::DataReaderStream<T>>>)`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `FusedFuture`:
              Box<F>
              futures::future::Shared<Fut>
              futures::futures_channel::oneshot::Receiver<T>
              OwnedMutexLockFuture<T>
              MutexLockFuture<'_, T>
              futures::future::future::flatten::Flatten<Fut, <Fut as futures::Future>::Output>
              futures::future::Fuse<Fut>
              futures::future::future::map::Map<Fut, F>
            and 60 others
    = note: required for `Pin<&mut (Result<Sample<T, <T as Keyed>::K>, rustdds::dds::Error>, usize, Vec<SelectNextSome<'_, rustdds::with_key::DataReaderStream<T>>>)>` to implement `FusedFuture`
    = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::select_internal` which comes from the expansion of the macro `select` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Even with only one `select_all` call I've got this error in the `select!` macro. I cannot directly await the `select_all` calls since I need to listen to all the futures at the same time.

Comment: You should use [`select_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.28/futures/future/fn.select_all.html) to listen to all the streams at the same time.

Comment: @Jmb I did not manage to use a select_all because I need to put two `select_all` (one for the data stream, and one for the events stream) + 1 next().fuse() for my stop message. This forces me to not directly `await` for the select all, but to put it in a select!{} macro.

I tried to use `select!` macro to gather these three futures in one async block, but I've got an error that I can't manage to fix.
I Edited the question to give more context

Comment: Use an `enum Message` to unify the types of your streams, `map` to convert the types on the fly (with e.g. `data_reader.async_sample_stream().map (Message::Data)`), and a single `select_all` to `await` them all at once.